# How to display similar column from different Content Types as a single column in listview?

Tags: 2010, content-type, list-view

- I have "Content Type A" and "Content Type B" both in a single Document Library.
- A has a column "A Status".
- B has a column "B Status".
- They are both "Choice" columns just with different choices.

Is there a way to have these columns display merged into a single column in a listview? Simply giving them both a DisplayName of "Status" just leaves me with two columns named "Status". Preferably in the list definition xml, but if you know a way through the UI, I can probably export and figure out the syntax myself.

Answer (score 0):

Create the list view with A Status column only. Then open the view in designer and drop B Status field inside A Status field (inside the same td of A Status)

Comment: When I open the view in Designer, I don't see any `<td>`s, just a bunch of `<ParameterBinding `. Am I doing it wrong? I'm in 2013, does that make a difference?

Comment: @apex yes this approach won't work in 2013.