# Can a content type item inherit sibling column values from lookup column item?

Tags: 2013, content-type, list-view, lookup-column, site-column

Here is how I have my lists structured - in case it matters, `List A` does not currently utilize Content Types.

[image: List Structure]

The problem is in the `List B` view of `Site Column B`.

[image: Compare Outputs]

Since `Content Type Y` doesn't directly reference `Site Column B`, there is no data populated in that column for all `Y` content types. I had hoped that column would be inherited from `List A` via the lookup `List A: Column A`, but this is apparently not the case.

### What I've Tried

I thought I could just force `List B` to pull in `Site Column B` with the lookup of `List A: Column A` by placing a check in the column settings under `Add a column to show each of these additional fields:`, but I guess `Choice` columns are not eligible for that?

So I found another question recommending [cloning a choice column in to a calculated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505050/get-extra-column-with-sharepoint-lookup-column). This allowed me to select the clone as an `additional field`, and got `Column B` data into `List B` for the `Type Y` items, but `Site Column B Clone` showed up as a different column than the `Type X` `Site Column B`.

[image: Cloned Column]

In order to map those two sets of data in to one column, I was going to attempt [editing the list view in SharePoint Designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118656/how-to-display-similar-column-from-different-content-types-as-a-single-column-in) as recommended in another question, but after quickly hitting a roadblock, the answer author verified that solution wouldn't work for 2013.

Any tips on continuing my attempts? Anyone have a new direction to try?

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't add Site Column B into Content Type Y? Since it looks like you want to display it in the list view? If you don't want users to have to enter it, you could make it hidden for that content type (or ShowInEditForm/ShowInNewForm = false) and still show it in the view

Comment: If I add it to `Type Y`, but hide it, will it inherity from `List A`? The reasoning is to reduce errors (and save user clicks). This site's purpose is corporate application information. `List B` is the list of applications, and the content types are types of applications (custom developed apps `X`, and packaged OOB type apps `Y`, with the package/platform it is built on as `List A`). `Site Column B` is the permission model. The idea is that if `application Y` is based on `platform A`, it will always use `permission model B`, but `custom app X` will need its permission model defined directly.

Comment: If both Column A and Site Column B are in the same content type, then you can add one of them as a lookup and select the other as a dependent column, where I'm pretty sure it will be correctly filled automatically even if it's hidden

Comment: Wow, that'd be easy! I'll try that tomorrow, and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Louis, but no dice - I'm unable to add `Site Column B` as a dependent column since it is a choice column.